# What does upgrading modify?

Tags: upgrade

Does upgrading leave all of my applications and personal information untouched?

Comment: I have tried to reword your question while preserving its meaning. If I have changed the meaning of your question at all, please feel free to edit it again.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "upgrade"?  Do you mean the `apt-get upgrade` command?  or do you mean a distribution upgrade?  The phrase "upgrade" or "upgrading" is extremely ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading Ubuntu will leave all of your personal files untouched, and it should leave almost all of your settings untouched.  If you have made low-level customizations by for example editing files under `/etc`, you may find that they need adjustment after the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading Ubuntu just updates the repositories.

It's like a normal Update, but it changes the repositories first.

Upgrading you distro will leave almost all of your settings untouched (just some will be removed, when gnome gets upgraded, for example). Upgrading your distro will leave ALL of your personal files untouchced.

I agree with poolie, just if you have made low-level customizations, you have to adjust them after the upgrade.

I hope this helped you,

Daniel

Comment: -1: Upgrading upgrades all packages.  There have recently been several upgrades to grub in maverick.  Upgrading to the new distribution just switches to the new repository and upgrades using the packages there.

Comment: @psusi Thank you for the information, I always thought normal updates doesn't update essential packages. Edited my post.